# Values changing upon form submission (Dropdown form)

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

Unfortunately, I could not think of a better title than the one I used. So my issue is that I have a form which connects to the database and holds various information. I am able to create, read and update this data but when it comes to updating without changing any data issues arise.

What this does is it allows me to edit players/users data through the use of form features such as text inputs and dropdown menus.

So essentially the problem is, if I were to open this to edit a pre-existing player then press the submit button without touching anything else, the first name and last name will be the same; however, the team ID and position will change to `0` in the database. If I were to inspect element, it does show the correct number; in this case it is (Team ID = 3 and Position = 6).

Here is the database query (PDO):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM players, teams WHERE playerid = ? AND players.teamid = teams.teamid";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$info = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0];
```

Note: This query gets all the needed data for the form and works perfectly in pulling this data out.

Now the form is where I believe the issue sort of stems from. Here is the full form taken out of the same PHP file:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
                                    <!-- text input -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>First Name</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $info['firstName']; ?>" value="<?php echo $info['firstName']; ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Last Name</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $info['lastName']; ?>" value="<?php echo $info['lastName']; ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Team ID</label><br/>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="teamid">
                                            <option value="<?php echo $info['teamid']; ?>" disabled="enabled" selected="selected"><?php echo $info['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
                                                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                                                $stmt->execute();
                                                $i = 0;
                                                    while ($teamListRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                                        $teamListArray[$i]['teamid']  = $teamListRow['teamid'];
                                                        $teamListArray[$i]['name'] = $teamListRow['name'];
                                                        echo "<option value='{$teamListArray[$i]['teamid']}'>{$teamListArray[$i]['name']}</option>";
                                                        $i++;
                                                    }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>                                    
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                      <label>Position</label><br/>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="position">
                                            <option value="<?php echo $info['position']; ?>" disabled="enabled" selected="selected">
                                            <?php 
                                            if($info['position'] == 1) {
                                                echo "1 - Loosehead Prop";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 2) {
                                                echo "2 - Hooker";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 3) {
                                                echo "3 - Tighthead Prop";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 4) {
                                                echo "4 - Second Row";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 5) {
                                                echo "5 - Second Row";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 6) {
                                                echo "6 - Blindside Flanker";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 7) {
                                                echo "7 - Openside Flanker";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 8) {
                                                echo "8 - Number Eight";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 9) {
                                                echo "9 - Scrum-Half";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 10) {
                                                echo "10 - Fly-Half";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 11) {
                                                echo "11 - Left Wing";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 12) {
                                                echo "12 - Inside Centre";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 13) {
                                                echo "13 - Outside Centre";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 14) {
                                                echo "14 - Right Wing";
                                            } elseif($info['position'] == 15) {
                                                echo "15 - Full Back"; 
                                            } else {
                                                echo "16/20 - Reserve";
                                            }

                                             ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <option value='1'>1 - Loosehead Prop</option>
                                            <option value='2'>2 - Hooker</option>
                                            <option value='3'>3 - Tighthead Prop</option>
                                            <option value='4'>4 - Second Row</option>
                                            <option value='5'>5 - Second Row</option>
                                            <option value='6'>6 - Bindside Flanker</option>
                                            <option value='7'>7 - Openside Flanker</option>
                                            <option value='8'>8 - Number Eight</option>
                                            <option value='9'>9 - Scrum-Half</option>
                                            <option value='10'>10 - Fly-Hald</option>
                                            <option value='11'>11 - Left Wing</option>
                                            <option value='12'>12 - Inside Centre</option>
                                            <option value='13'>13 - Outside Centre</option>
                                            <option value='14'>14 - Right Wing</option>
                                            <option value='15'>15 - Full Back</option>
                                            <option value='16'>16 - Reserve</option>
                                            <option value='17'>17 - Reserve</option>
                                            <option value='18'>18 - Reserve</option>
                                            <option value='19'>19 - Reserve</option>
                                            <option value='20'>20 - Reserve</option>
                                        </select>                                    
                                     </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box-footer">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" style="margin-left:-10px;" />
                                    </div>

                                     </form>
```

## NOTE: everything works up until the point I hit submit! Once I hit submit the two dropdown menus change their result into a 0

P.s: Sorry if I did a bad job of explaining, please don't thrash me and also try give constructive criticism where possible as after all I am still learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of `disabled="enabled" selected="selected"` in your options for the two `<select>` dropdowns.

First you are disabling that option than you are marking it as selected.

Remove `disabled="enabled"` and try..

Comment: You have got to be joking me! I could of sworn I got rid of that earlier! Thank you very much for your help, I've been staring at it for so long!